# How can i send push notification on any item update event in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

**I am using parse for my application**

*I have one fragment on user which have to write article and save on parse but with not approve*

*when admin approve that user filed I want to send push notification automatically to that user with  particular article is approved message*

**How can I implement this things..?**

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Data", function(request) {var dirtyKeys = request.object.dirtyKeys();for (var i = 0; i < dirtyKeys.length; ++i) {
var dirtyKey = dirtyKeys[i];
if (dirtyKey === "name") {
//Get value from Data Object
              var username = request.object.get("name");

              //Set push query
              var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
              pushQuery.equalTo("name",username);

              //Send Push message
              Parse.Push.send({
                              where: pushQuery,
                              data: {
                              alert: "Name Updated",
                              sound: "default"
                              }
                              },{
                              success: function(){
                              response.success('true');
                              },
                              error: function (error) {
                              response.error(error);
                              }
             });


  return;  } } response.success();});
```

Comment: With Cloud Code triggers: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide

Comment: yeah. but how can i fire trigger when user article filed status is updated by admin to approve

Comment: Use afterSave trigger and dirty to know if `status` has been modified: http://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#dirty

Comment: object.dirty("status") returns if it has been changed

Comment: @bigdestroyer I was try but its not work

Answer (score 0):

If this is a matter of just hitting "approve", I would create a cloud code function for "Approve article" that is called by the admin tapping an approve button. This function sets the approve status and then calls a function (still in cloud code) for sending the push message to the user.

More on cloud code functions: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functionshttps://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions

Alternatively the approve button can change status and save the document, and then an `afterSave()` function in cloud code can handle the push. This is less clear, though, since the `afterSave()` function will always be called when the record is saved, and it would need to check for status and only send push if the article has been approved.